# Extract elements from a nested list w/o a loop

Tags: r, list

Assume that I have the following data structure:

```
l <- list(pos1 = list(a = 1, b = 1, c = "a"),
          pos2 = list(a = 2, b = 2, c = "b", d = "u"))
```

I want now to get a vector of all `a` and `b` elements. I could do that easily with a loop:

```
a <- b <- vector("numeric", length(l))
for (i in seq_along(l)) {
   a[[i]] <- l[[i]]$a
   b[[i]] <- l[[i]]$b
}
a
# [1] 1 2
b
# [1] 1 2
```

My question is now, is there any (vectorized?) way of doing it without the loop? Or is the loop already the "best" solution?

Comment: A loop is the only solution, but typically you would use a `lapply` loop, e.g., `sapply(l, "[[", "a")`.

Comment: You could try something like this: `a <- unname(unlist(l)[grepl(".a",names(unlist(l)))])
b <- unname(unlist(l)[grepl(".b",names(unlist(l)))])

`

Comment: @Roland A loop is not the only solution

Comment: @Hack-R It's the only safe and often the most efficient solution.

Comment: `lapply` solution would require to be repeated for each element I would like to extract, so `for` should be better in this case.

Comment: @Roland That's wildly inaccurate

Comment: @thothal In this specific example (where the desired elements are numeric and of length one), you could just do `sapply(l, "[", j = c("a", "b"))`. The point is that loops are the standard way for working on lists and usually they are quite fast. If they aren't, I would reconsider the data structure. Coercing the list into a vector (as others recommended) is dangerous if you have different classes in your list. It also copies the data in memory, which can also be slow.

Comment: "I want now to get a vector of all a and b elements." - but your example code creates *two* vectors, `a` and `b`. Is that what you really want or would a data frame do?

Comment: @thothal You are going to be iterating over a structure at some point; doing it via `apply()` would set the loop up in R-land, via `sapply` or `lapply` in C-land. But they are all looping. Both `sapply` and `lapply` are well suited here (some would say `vapply` instead of `sapply` for robustness...) and efficient. They are also clear and easy to read. Vectorisation is a goal if you are doing something inefficiently where a vectorised fun already exists; it is rare that you can beat a `for` or `l|s|vapply` for examples like your's without resorting to C, and even then...

Comment: Of course we have to iterate over the structure at some point. I also agree that in general the `* apply` family is a better option (due to `C` implementation), but we also agree that ONE iterations (regardless in which language) is always faster than TWO iterations. Hence, in this case where I want to create another data structure, I feel that the `for` is better suited than the `*apply`, if (and that was my question) there's no vectorized form already.

Comment: @thotal I'm not sure this is necessarily true. A `lapply` or `for` loop is pretty optimized and what takes the most time is usually the function calls within the loops (e.g., `[[` and `$`, which are of course relatively fast for lists). It might well be that two `lapply` loops are not slower than your one `for` loop (benchmark on a list with many sublists). And code readability is a value in itself.

Comment: `l <- list(pos1 = list(a = rep(1,100), b = seq(1,50), c = "a"),
          pos2 = list(a = 2, b = 2, c = "b", d = "u"))`

Comment: @Hack-R I am not sure about the rules of reposting again.  But, since you made a post on dodging, I thought about commenting.  I have nothing against you and believe me, I have stopped that practice after your post.

Answer (score 2):

If you could guarantee the number of elements in `l` would be equal to the number of elements in each element of `l`, you might be able to pull this off without a loop.  But as a generic solution, you will need a loop somewhere to do this.

Does the following produce what you want? (It could be adapted to only search for `a` and `b`).

```
reorganize_list <- function(l)
{
  unique_elements <- 
    unique(unlist(lapply(l, function(x) unique(names(x)))))

  L <- vector("list", length(unique_elements))
  L <- setNames(L, unique_elements)

  for (i in seq_along(L))
  {
    L[[i]] <- unname(unlist(sapply(l, function(x) x[names(L)[i]])))
  }

  L
}


l <- list(pos1 = list(a = 1, b = 1, c = "a"),
          pos2 = list(a = 2, b = 2, c = "b", d = "u"))

reorganize_list(l)
```

#### Edits and commentary

With a little more effort, I'm sure I could come up with a solution that doesn't require a `for` loop.  But I am not optimistic that it would be a "better" solution (with better being a pretty subjective term).

For instance, we could easily convert each element of the list to a data frame and bind all the rows together.  We could accomplish this in a few lines of code:

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
lapply(l, as_tibble) %>%
  bind_rows()
```

We still ought to weigh the advantages and disadvantages. The advantage of `reorganize_list` and the tibble approach I've used here are that they can accommodate an arbitrary length `l` where each `l[[i]]` has arbitrary length and names.  Granted, you're only pursuing `a` and `b`, and with only two vectors needed in the result, you may not value that level of generalizability.

The key advantages to your original solution and Hack-R's solution are that they are simplistic to read. The disadvantage is that if you need more than just the two vectors, you will have to individually code each one.

Let's also take into account computational efficiency.  I've timed the four approaches discussed in this question, and the results are given below.

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  #* A tibble solution
  tibble = {lapply(l, as_tibble) %>%
              bind_rows()},

  #* The reorganize_list solution
  reorganize = reorganize_list(l),

  #* Hack-R solution
  dframe = data.frame(a = unlist(l)[grepl(".a",names(unlist(l)))], 
                      b = unlist(l)[grepl(".b",names(unlist(l)))],
                      row.names = NULL),

  #* Your original solution
  orig = {a <- b <- vector("numeric", length(l))
          for (i in seq_along(l)) {
            a[[i]] <- l[[i]]$a
            b[[i]] <- l[[i]]$b
          }}
)

Unit: microseconds
       expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq      max neval  cld
     tibble 366.260 390.1590 416.52197 402.7685 414.0585 1589.669   100    d
 reorganize 104.101 122.5755 130.29376 132.2530 138.7035  155.418   100  b  
     dframe 333.124 357.0230 371.36554 369.4855 381.3620  546.897   100   c 
       orig   5.865   8.2110  10.00567  10.5570  11.4370   16.128   100 a
```

So as it turns out, your original solution with the `for` loop is *by far* the fastest solution.  Even with the caveat that this is such a small object on which to time anything, I suspect that the `for` loop will remain faster than the other solutions as the scale of the problem goes (I don't have the same confidence that `reorganize` will remain faster than the others).

I think we've demonstrated by now the the `for` loop may not be the *only* solution, but there's a good case that it is the *best* solution for the problem.

Comment: Well, your solution still uses a `for` loop (and an `sapply` loop) and is by far more difficult to read.

Comment: I share the sentiment with others that `for` loops are not always a evil that should be avoided.  Sometimes they are the right tool for the job.  I will agree that my code is more difficult to read. It wouldn't be hard to rewrite it for clarity (unnesting functions, etc), but I'll note that part of the reason of putting it into a function is to hide the ugly code and give you the option of accomplishing the task in a single call. (admittedly, only of value if you have to do this often). See my edits for more.